# If Tar’s relationship with Krista was obvious, why didn't Sharon and Francesca leave before?

Tags: plot-explanation, tar

The movie tells us that Tar's behavior was to groom young women. She would take young artists, promise them success, love them, and leave them. Both Sharon and Francesca were aware of this and seemed to have no problems. Even when Tar chooses Olga to go to Nyc, Sharon does not have a problem and you find out she never slept with Francesca.

**Why didn't Sharon and Francesca leave?**